# How to efficiently re-arrange pass/fail as a pass percentage by day in Pandas and NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to analyze data that has this form...

```
date     | result | test
----------------------------
10-08-13 | True   | test_1
10-08-13 | True   | test_2
10-08-13 | False  | test_2
10-07-13 | True   | test_3
10-07-13 | False  | test_4
10-06-13 | True   | test_3
10-05-13 | False  | test_1
```

What i'm looking to create is a time series of pass percentage over time for each test. So ideally i'd like to re-arrange the data into this form:

```
date     | test_1 | test_2  | test_3  | test_4
-----------------------------------------------
10-08-13 | 50     | 70      | 55      | 100
10-08-13 | 60     | 70      | 55      | 100
10-08-13 | 30     | 70      | 55      | NaN
10-07-13 | 50     | 10      | NaN     | 100
10-07-13 | 30     | 10      | NaN     | 100
10-06-13 | 50     | 70      | Nan     | 100
10-05-13 | 50     | 70      | 55      | 100
```

So far i've been able to re-arrange the data using this code:

```
all_tests = data.groupby('test').size()
data_grouped = data.groupby('date')
per_test_per_day = {}

def tests_per_day(group):
    g = group.groupby('test')
    tests = g.size() 
    tests_pass = g['result'].sum()
    for d in all_tests.index:
    if d not in per_test_per_day:
        per_device_per_day[d] = []

    if d in tests:
        per_test_per_day[d].append(tests_pass[d] / tests[d] * 100)
    else:
        per_test_per_day[d].append(NaN)

data_grouped.apply(tests_per_day)
```

The resulting data frame looks close to what I need except it's indexes are just standard integers and so my X-Axis is not labelled with correct dates.

I'm sure there is a vastly better way of accomplishing this data conversion using Pandas and NumPy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I think about it this is *much* better written as a [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.pivot.pivot_table.html):

```
In [21]: df.pivot_table(values='result', cols='test', rows='date')
Out[21]: 
test      test_1  test_2  test_3  test_4
date                                    
10-05-13       0     NaN     NaN     NaN
10-06-13     NaN     NaN       1     NaN
10-07-13     NaN     NaN       1       0
10-08-13       1     0.5     NaN     NaN

In [22]: df.pivot_table(values='result', cols='test', rows='date') * 100
Out[22]: 
test      test_1  test_2  test_3  test_4
date                                    
10-05-13       0     NaN     NaN     NaN
10-06-13     NaN     NaN     100     NaN
10-07-13     NaN     NaN     100       0
10-08-13     100      50     NaN     NaN
```

*Note: the default aggfunc is mean which is just what you want.*

See this answer's edit history for a less direct way using groupby, mean and unstack.

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm. However i'm fuzzy on exactly what the unstack operation does. The Pandas documentation on that function doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: @FraserGraham It's basically a pivot to turn the test level a set of columns, which made me realise what you are doing is just a pivot! ahem!

Comment: That makes more sense now. I understand pivot tables from working with them in Excel years back. The stack and unstack operations make a little more sense to me now in this context.